# What is the difference between "*" and "*:*" in solr

Tags: solr

What is the difference between `*` and `* : *` in solr 4.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Queries are equivalent to :-

`q=*` --> default search `field:*`
Wildcard query would be fired on default search if field specified

`q=*:*` --> All `Fields:*`
It would fire wildcard query on that all fields. Usually used to get all results from a Collection.

Comment: Yes.. this will answer my question

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

* is wildcard character which indicates the zero or more occurrence of the preceding characters. For example if there is an indexed word Stackoverflow, then you can search it using Stackover* which will find the indexed word.

On the other hand, *:* is used with the main query (q) to get all documents from the index (if no other parameters set).